# RewriteRule two actions at the same time

Tags: .htaccess, logging

.htaccess file has an action- the page */permission denied* being displayed if the user is blocked.

Is it possible to do both - show block pages and add information in log file at the same time?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteRule .* /permission-denied [R,L]
#RewriteRule .* /log.php?log [END,NE,E=nG:%1___%2___%3]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you.....

Comment: No, you can not give two responses to one request. Either make the `/permission denied` (does that even work, with the unencoded space there in the substitution URL?) "page" do the logging itself; or internally _rewrite_ the request for that URL, to your logging script. (But either way, the same script will have to provide both the page content, and do the logging.)

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake with the space /permission-denied

Answer (score 0):

The reason this won't work is that the `RewriteRule` doesn't "trigger an action", it just *changes the URL that's going to be processed* - that's what the "rewrite" in the name means.

For instance, you might have the following pair of rules:

```
RewriteRule a.abc /b.xyz
RewriteRule b.xyz /c.php
```

If the server receives a request for "/a.php", it processes these rules in order:

1. The first rule matches, so the URL is rewritten to "/b.xyz"
2. The second rule matches, so the URL is rewritten to "/c.php"
3. No more rules match, so the URL that gets processed is "/c.php"
4. The script at c.php is executed, and its response is sent back to the browser

The only way to perform an *action* for that request is to put the logic into the script at c.php